# Problema con XAMPP, CGI y C++. Como habilitar cgi?

Tags: html5, c++

Estoy tratando de hacer un pequeño CGI con C++ (todo por práctica) en el que intento coger los datos de un formulario en HTML y luego imprimirlos en una pantalla nueva. El caso es que siguiendo el tutorial, a la hora de ejecutarse el .exe, lo que hace es descargarlo y no lo ejecuta.

Estos son los códigos:

```
<body>
    <form action="prueba.exe" method="get">
        <input type="text" name="nombre" value="Nombre:" class="input">
        <input type="text" name="apellido" value="Apellido:" class="input">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Aceptar" class="button">
    </form>
</body>
```

Y el C++ es:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    cout << "content-type: text/html" << endl;

    string data = getenv("QUERY_STRING");
    cout << data << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ¿ Servidor WEB empleado ? Estos, por seguridad, no dejan que se ejecute **cualquier** archivo; tienen una opción para indicar un directorio especial para ello, o bien una lista de extensiones.

Comment: @trauma estoy usando XAMPP en local

Comment: Yo que tu cambiaba la pregunta a algo parecido a ¿ Como habilitar mi *cgi* en XAMPP ? o algo similar. Estoy 100% seguro de que el problema es de configuración del servidor. No tengo mucha experiencia en ello, y es **muy** antigua :-(